# Clases EmbeddedObject con real swift

Tags: swift

I am working with Realm swift
In my case I have these models

```
class User: Object {
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
  @Persisted var name: String
  @Persisted var books: List<Book>
}

class Book: EmbeddedObject {
  @Persisted var name: String
  @Persisted var edition: String
}
```

Adding a book, but now I want to update the name of that book that I add, in the property @Persisted var books: List

Could you guide me how I can update said element of the List @Persisted var books: List of a specific user?